# Nuget package is not compatible, but in the supported-list (StrawberryShake.Tools)

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, hotchocolate, strawberryshake

I got this message after creating a new .NET 5-project (in VS2019) and trying to install nuget-package StrawberryShake.Tools. This seems a bit strange, since it says both that it is and it isnt compatible with "net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)"

> Error NU1202  Package StrawberryShake.Tools 12.6.0 is not compatible
> with net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0). Package StrawberryShake.Tools
> 12.6.0 supports:
>
> - net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0) / any
> - net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) / any
> - netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1) / any

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I followed the [official installation guide](https://chillicream.com/docs/strawberryshake/v12/get-started/console) instead. The steps are as follows:

1. Open a terminal and navigate to e.g. the project where you want the package to be installed.
2. Run `dotnet new tool-manifest`.
3. Run `dotnet tool install StrawberryShake.Tools --local`. The nuget package has now been installed in *~/.nuget/packages* and may be used in the project.